# Debugging Perl with Visual Studio Code

Tags: perl, visual-studio-code

I have just started with Perl today and installed [ActivePerl](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ActivePerl) 5.24.1 and everything went well. I was able to create my test program `testPerl.pl` with simple a `print` command and run it through `console`.

Now I wanted to use Visual Studio Code to run my Perl script, and so I opened the project folder [testPerl.pl location] with Visual Studio Code and tried to debug the code. I have installed the [`Perl-Debug`](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=mortenhenriksen.perl-debug) extension in the editor and when I hit <kbd>F5</kbd>, Visual Studio Code asked me to **Select Environment** and I chose the **Perl Debug** option, which actually created the `launch.json` file for me with the below contents.

```
{
    "version": "0.0.2",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "type": "perl",
            "request": "launch",
            "exec": "perl",
            "name": "Perl-Debug",
            "root": "${workspaceRoot}/",
            "program": "${workspaceRoot}/${command.AskForProgramName}",
            "inc": [],
            "stopOnEntry": true
        }
    ]
}
```

I have kept default values as it, and when I hit <kbd>F5</kbd> again, it asked me for a command with default value `test.pl`. It is because of `${command.AskForProgramName}`, I assume. I entered my file name `testPerl.pl` in the command, but then nothing happens. It starts and ends without any `print` in console.

How can I actually configure this `launch.json` file or is there another way I need to do this?

Comment: In [this doc](https://code.visualstudio.com/Docs/editor/debugging) it says _Please note that the attributes available in these launch configurations vary from debugger to debugger. You can use IntelliSense to find out which attributes exist for a specific debugger._

Comment: @simbabque Agreed, and it is as expected and creates its own auto-generated `launch.json` file and according to its auto generated file, it is as similar as what we execute in command line..

Comment: Unfortunately I don't have access to a Windows box where I am allowed to install an ActivePerl so I cannot try. It certainly looks right. Is there some way to get what it's doing into the log panel of your VSCode?

Comment: I wish I could give you the details if it gets logged but unfortunately nothing logs in the Editor..

Answer (score 3):

I tried with a newer version of the plugin: [Perl Debug](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=mortenhenriksen.perl-debug) version 0.2.0.

This works out of the box. The proposed configuration looks as follows:

```javascript
{
    // Use IntelliSense to learn about possible attributes.
    // Hover to view descriptions of existing attributes.
    // For more information, visit: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=830387
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "type": "perl",
            "request": "launch",
            "name": "Perl-Debug local",
            "program": "${workspaceFolder}/${relativeFile}",
            "exec": "perl",
            "execArgs": [],
            "root": "${workspaceRoot}/",
            "inc": [],
            "args": [],
            "env": {},
            "stopOnEntry": true
        },
        {
            "type": "perl",
            "request": "launch",
            "name": "Perl-Debug remote",
            "program": "${workspaceFolder}/${relativeFile}",
            "root": "${workspaceRoot}/",
            "stopOnEntry": true,
            "port": 5000
        }
    ]
}
```

Do note I tried this out on a Mac, with Visual Studio Code version 1.24.0.

Comment: For what is the Per-Debug remote?

Comment: The link to Perl Debug Plugin is not valid anymore!

Answer (score 1):

I ran Visual Studio Code on a Mac and changed

```
"program": "${workspaceRoot}/${command.AskForProgramName}"
```

to

```
"program": "${file}"
```

to get the current file to debug.

Answer (score 0):

`"inc":['some/path']` doesn’t work for me but I successfully tried to specify paths in `.vscode/settings.json`:

```json
{
  "perl.perlInc": ["."]
}
```

See https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=richterger.perl

Answer (score 0):

Please install perl debug adapter from the market place and launch.json should look something like below
{

```
"version": "0.2.0",
"configurations": [
    {
        "type": "perl",
        "request": "launch",
        "name": "Perl-Debug",
        "program": "${workspaceFolder}/${relativeFile}",
        "stopOnEntry": true,
        "reloadModules": true
    }
]
```